# hataccess redirect with variable

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect

I'm trying to pass a variable in htaccess, I have to rewrite this address:

http:// site.com/en/profilo-del-cane/userprofile/avatar3
to 
http:// site.com/en/dogs-profile/userprofile/avatar3

avatar3 is a variable, iv tried these, not work

```
RewriteRule ^/en/profilo-del-cane/userprofile/?$ http:// site.com/en/dogs-profile/userprofile/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

i'm ceck these on http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify any capturing notation inside your search regex. Have a try with this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/en/profilo-del-cane/userprofile/(.*)$   http://some.site.com/en/dog-profiles/userprofile/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: "not works" does not help. What happens? Any error messages? What is in the log files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(en)/profilo-del-cane/(userprofile/.*)$ /$1/dog-profiles/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```